# Create distributable app version for IOS using Xcode 3.2

Tags: ios, executable, distribution, xcode3.2

I developed an app and tested in iPhone and iPad simulators. In the project there's .app file in debug-iphonesimulator folder. Doesn't look like "release" file for me, because of the folder's name.

All I want to do now is create the app file which is going to be submitted later to the stores. I find information about a lot of things - test app on one device, create developer account, install add hoc distrubution and whatever. All I want to know is which is the file I have to submit to testers and store later and how I create it.

In Android you export app and have .apk at the end for all devices. But I don't understand how it is for IOS.

**Edit: I'm particulary interested in the case where the developer is not the one owning developer account. What does have to send the developer to the person owning the account?**

I'm using Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: No answers? I thought I would get 10 responses in 1 minute from IOS developers :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of xCode, all you need to do is go to product->archive, and it will assemble the binary and package it for submission to the app store.  There is a little bit more to preparing for distribution, such as creating a distribution profile, but you can find that information on the developer website for apple

Comment: And if I'm not the person with the developer account, what do I have to send to the person who has it?

Comment: Just right click on the entry in the archive view in the organizer window, and you can send that file to whoever you need to I believe

Comment: I'm using Xcode 3.2.6. Sorry for not mentioning that first, edited now.

Comment: Hmm, its been quite a while since I've used 3.2,  the option to archive should still be there somewhere around the build options, and then its just a matter of finding that archived file and emailing it.  I know thats not all that helpful, but I really just can't remember where all of it was before

Comment: Come to think of it, I think what you have to do is create a distribution build setting that is a copy of the release, and tell it to use your distribution profile, then build for that configuration, and then right click on the target on the left and select "show in finder", then you have to zip that file/folder and that is what you need for submission

Comment: Ok. But that's a different .zip than if I just zip the whole project, right? If I send them a file with the whole project they need to have Xcode installed to do something with it. If I send the zip you are talking about, they can upload directly to devices or app store? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I am not talking about putting the whole project into a .zip, just the compiled binary

Comment: But in the folder of the project there's already build folder and there is a debug-iphonesimulator folder containing binaries. You are talking about that folder with different settings -> release right? what is my distribution profile? sorry lost :/

Comment: Assuming you have a developer account, go to https://developer.apple.com/ios/my/distribution/index.action and review the process for prepping a build for distribution.

Comment: But what I'm talking about is I *don't* have a developer account but I have to deliver something to the person which has developer account (which is not an IOS developer), so he can test and later upload to the store. So I wonder if I can without developer account deliver him release binaries, or if I'm forced to deliver whole project for him to produce the release binaries. See...?

Comment: In order to submit, you need a distribution profile generated by the holder of the developer account, that file can be transferred as well, but before then, all you can send is a release binary that he can test on provisioned devices